# How do I set the version string of my flatpak application?

Tags: flatpak, flatpak-builder

When I run `flatpak list` some applications have a version:

```
$ flatpak list
Name                                     Application ID                                  Version             Branch       Origin         Installation
Cambalache                               ar.xjuan.Cambalache                             0.10.3              stable       flathub        system
ungoogled-chromium                       com.github.Eloston.UngoogledChromium            112.0.5615.165      stable       flathub        system
Codecs                                   com.github.Eloston.UngoogledChromium.Codecs                         stable       flathub        system
Flatseal                                 com.github.tchx84.Flatseal                      1.8.1               stable       fedora         system
OBS Studio                               com.obsproject.Studio                           29.0.2              stable       flathub        system
My Example App                           org.example.App                                                     master       remote1-origin user
```

I want my application to have this column reflect its actual version too, but after searching for a way to set it for several days, I came up with nothing. It's not mentioned anywhere in the flatpak or flatpak-builder documentation...

Do I have to add it as a field in my .json app manifest? Or is it a flag to `flatpak-builder` or `flatpak build-bundle`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I figured it out. What I needed is a metainfo.xml file (or an appdata.xml file). Flatpak reads this file (specifically, the `<releases>` tag) and sets the Version column to the version string of the latest release.

The only problem that remains is that some applications install it as `*.appdata.xml` and others call it `*.metainfo.xml`.

The flatpak documentation contradicts itself on this matter:
https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/freedesktop-quick-reference.html#appdata-files
https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/conventions.html#appdata-files

But I guess this is a separate question.

Comment: did you figure this out?
I have the appdata file, but still don't get any version.
https://github.com/syco/com.zoiper.Zoiper

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

AFTER build-finish but BEFORE build-export:

```
mkdir -p "$BDIR/files/share/app-info/xmls"
cat "$BDIR/files/share/metainfo/"* | sed 1d | gzip > "$BDIR/files/share/app-info/xmls/$FID.xml.gz"
$BDIR -- build-dir, $FID -- flatpak application id, "sed 1d" -- removing "&lt;?xml ... ?&gt;" line
```